# how to run a thread automatically when i set up my web service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm new with WCF. I may set up several web services.
Now my question is how can i run a thread automatically when i set up my web services.
I want the thread to run automatically while setting up all my services rather than i call a web service and then the service create a thread. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: What's so special about this thread you want to create?

Comment: Could you use Global.ascx? and start a thread on Application Start?

Comment: nothing special. I just don't want to start the thread manually. I want it run after setting up the web service

Comment: I'll try the global.ascx. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: To  WraithNath : It does work! Thanks again! but it seems i can't accept the comment?